# validations error messages hash empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, error-handling, rails-models

Any idea why the messages hash would be empty in this situation?

I have these validations:

```
validates_presence_of :part_number
validates_uniqueness_of :part_number
```

a simple create:

```
if @part.save
  puts 'saved'
  redirect_to new_v2_path
else
  puts 'not saved'
  flash[:error] = "There was an error while updating the part."
  redirect_to new_v2_path(@part)
end
```

in the view:

```
<% if @part.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation" style="color: red;">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@part.errors.count, 'error') %> :</h2>

    <ul>
      <% @part.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

the error object:

```
...l, flush_part: nil>, @messages={}>
```

Comment: Where and how are you calling the error object? Is it being called after a save error or not?

Comment: It's being called in the view. I pasted the code above. My understanding is when it doesn't pass validation in the model would get a hash of the error messages.

Answer (score 1):

In your failed validation branch you are redirecting instead of rendering, generating a new request to `:new_2` action and instantiating a new `@part` object, with no value assigned and thus errors. You need to use `render` instead.

Change this line:

```
 redirect_to new_v2_path(@part)
```

To this one:

```
 render :new # or new_v2 or whatever action name you have.
```